# Objectify check if collection contains a value

Tags: google-app-engine, enums, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I've set with some values defined as `Enum`. Now I want to write a query which returns number of entites which have a specific `Enum` value in their set. I've tried it like below but it doesn't work (empty list of entities is returned).

```
public InfoCount getInfoCount(@Named("info") InfoType type) {
   ofy().load()
        .type(InfoRecord.class)
        .filter("infoTypes", type)
        .count()
}
```

`infoTypes` is declared as `Set<InfoType>`

It's simple to check if a value is in the collection using `in` but how to check it the other way - whether a collection contains value (or set of values) or not?

Comment: Check if you have @Index on the field.

Comment: @Ashish Works fine. I haven't had the `@Index` annotation on the `infoTypes` set. Could you post this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it?

Comment: Thanks Tom. Posted answer with details so that anybody looking at it can get the complete picture.

Comment: can I check is a collection contains a Key<?> ? Does not work for me, probably a Key issue. I have an Entity that contains a collection of Key<?> . I want to query Entities that have a specific Key<?> in their collection.

Comment: @vandus Querying `@Index List<Ref<MyEntity>> myEntities` with filter `myEntities = {{ MyEntity instance }}` works for me. Not sure about using Key instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datastore can be queried only by indexed fileds. Equality queries on multi-value properties are supported simply by passing field-name and value (the way you are doing it), but field must be indexed. Objectify has very intuitive support for enums, so that shouldn't be the problem. Indexing in Objectify is done using @Index on the field.